# php Fatal error: Cannot use lexical variable $eventName as a parameter name in

Tags: php, guzzle, php-7.2

I have the error as said in title in the following code (guzzle http lib) please tell me how to fix it manually. I have no idea about function() use () construct to be honest so dont know how to fix it.

```
public function once($eventName, callable $listener, $priority = 0) {
    $onceListener = function (
        EventInterface $event,
        $eventName
    ) use (&$onceListener, $eventName, $listener, $priority) {
        $this->removeListener($eventName, $onceListener);
        $listener($event, $eventName, $this);
    };

    $this->on($eventName, $onceListener, $priority);
}
```

Problem is with $eventName after use( construct.

Comment: You are trying to use 2 variables with the same name $eventName. Rename your parameters. Ex: `function (
        EventInterface $event,
        $eventName2
    ) use (...){}`

Comment: aha ok thx......

Comment: Read more about anonymous functions here: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, which was caused by incompatability between an older guzzle version and php 7. By updating guzzle to version 5.3.4 this issue was fixed.

```
$ composer update guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

Resulting in

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 0 installs, 1 update, 0 removals
  - Updating guzzlehttp/guzzle (5.3.0 => 5.3.4): Downloading (100%)
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```